# how can i plot histogram like this?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

i have a txt file, the file include

```
('computer', 1592)
('student', 1113)
('university', 1080)
('raspberry', 1000)
('science', 814)
('$5', 770)
('pi', 688)
('exam', 571)
('just', 544)
('intelligence', 495)
('solution', 475)
('costs', 423)
('exam:', 411)
('latest', 402)
('pi's', 366)
('be', 311)
('can', 268)
('what', 268)
('way', 257)
('students', 238)
```

[I want to plot it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg2yg.png)

How can i do it?

Comment: what have you tried so far?
See this example - http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/barchart_demo.html

Comment: i tried but didnt do it like picture

Comment: What did you try and what did it look like? It is hard to help without knowing what you have done so far

Comment: firstly i dint do it txt file to list

Comment: So, the question is essentially: how to parse this file?

Comment: first part yes, how to parse this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your file like this:

```
numbers = []
labels = []
with open('myfile.txt') as fobj:
    for line in fobj:
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        label, number = line.split(',')
        numbers.append(int(number.strip()[:-1]))
        labels.append(label[2:-1])
```

Now:

```
>>> print(numbers)
[1592, 1113, 1080, 1000, 814, 770, 688, 571, 544, 495, 475, 423, 411, 402,
 366, 311, 268, 268, 257, 238]
>>> labels
['computer', 'student', 'university', 'raspberry', 'science', '$5', 'pi',
 'exam', 'just', 'intelligence', 'solution', 'costs', 'exam:', 'latest', 
 "pi's", 'be', 'can', 'what', 'way', 'students']
```

Plotting:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = list(range(len(numbers)))
plt.bar(x, numbers)
plt.xticks(x, labels, rotation=90)
plt.savefig('hist.png', dpi=300)
```

[image]

Comment: error like this :label, number = line.split(',')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: Looks like an empty line. Added a fix for this. Also I tested for the data layout  you provided. If there is anything ls in the file, it won't work.

Comment: yes its working, thanks. now, how can i plot histogram like this picture?

Comment: I'm grateful to you really :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use matplotlib for plotting a histogram (See this link: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist).
For reading the file line by line there is the read function included in python(http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_read.htm).
To split the 2 comma separated values you can use the split function (on the resulting string of the read function) with the ',' as separation parameter.
I hope that is helpful for you.
To remove leading space symbols or brackets there is a function called strip(), which also works on strings.